# Prove $\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{e^{2n}-1}{n}*\cos(3/n)$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that $$\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{e^{2n}-1}{n}*\cos\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)$$

does not exist. We can say something about limit of $\cos\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)$ but no idea how to show that in more "formal" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{e^{2n}-1}{n} = 2\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{e^{2n}-e^0}{2n}= 2(e^x)'\vert_{x=0} = 2$$

Take $n_k = \dfrac{1}{(2k+1)\pi}$, we get one limit.

Take $n_k = \dfrac{1}{2k\pi}$, we get another limit.

These two limits are not equal

Comment: Can you explain more how you found the limit of first frac (with "e")?

Comment: @VirrageS the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$ is defined to be $\lim_{x\to 0 }\dfrac{e^x - 1}{x}$, which is equal to $\lim_{2n\to 0 }\dfrac{e^{2n} - 1}{2n}$ if we substitute $x =2n$

Comment: Okay, now I get it. Thanks.